# sqlalchemy запрос к БД с join не выводит данные если count равно нулю

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
async def get_user(id: UUID4, db: AsyncSession) -> dict:
    query = select(user_table, func.count(distinct(list_table.c.id)).label('list_count'), func.count(distinct(follower_table.c.follower_id)).label('follower_count'), func.count(distinct(passed_game_table.c.game_id)).label('passed_game_count')).join( follower_table, onclause=follower_table.c.user_id==user_table.c.id).join(list_table, onclause=list_table.c.owner_id==user_table.c.id).join(passed_table, onclause=passed_table.c.user_id==user_table.c.id).join(passed_game_table, onclause=passed_game_table.c.list_id==passed_table.c.id).group_by(user_table).where(user_table.c.id == id)
    result = await db.execute(query)
    print(result.all())
    return result.all()
```

Всем привет, есть такая функция, которая выводит кол-во подписчиков, списков и игр конкретного пользователя, но вот если хоть чего то у пользователя нет, то результат не выводиться никакой, при этом sql запрос выводит 0, в случае если чего то нет вообще. Нужно чтобы выводило пользователя не зависимо от того ноль у него подписчиков или 100.
Использую sqlalchemy 2.0

Вот sql запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: убедитесь что `join()` в коде делает именно `left join`. Вернее, очевидно, что он делает простой `join`, и исправить надо на `left`

Comment: и лучше перепишите это подзапросами. Нет смысла составлять там декартово произведение этих таблиц, и считать дистинкты потом. Память потратите, время потратите, эффектновсть никакая.

Comment: Спасибо большое  @teran , можете пожалуйста оформить в качестве ответа чтобы я отметил подсказку как правильную)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В отличие от приведенного вами SQL кода с использованием `LEFT JOIN`, код гериуемый `->join()` методами формирует `JOIN/INNER JOIN` соединения, что в полной мере соответствует описанному вами поведению относительно отсутствия записей. Возможно, в используемой библиотеке имеются какие-либо методы вида `leftJoin()`, используйте их.

Тем не менее, выбранная стратегия построения запроса не кажется особо эффективной, поскольку для подсчета количества фолловеров и т.п. вы строите запрос, который пересекает строки увеличивая результирующий набор данных. То есть получаете `1*L*F*G` строк а потом уже начинаете считать у уникальные. При этом, например для список у вас каждое уникальное значение будет повтряться `F*G` раз.
В данном случае, эффективней использовать коррелирующие подзапросы,никаких произведений таблиц тогда не будет в принципе, и `ditinct` и группировки так же не потребуются.

```
SELECT
     u.username
   , (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM follower AS f
      WHERE f.user_id = u.id
     ) AS followers
   , (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM list AS l
      WHERE l.owner_id = u.id
     ) AS list
   , ...
FROM users AS u 
WHERE u.username = '...'
```

Также для таких запросов (не важно этот, или ваш вариант) должны иметься индексы на столбцах `user_id, owner_id` и прочих, по которым происходит фильтрация. В целом если вы создавали внешние ключи для этих таблиц, то индексы были созданы автоматически